# range.Formula throwing COMException with extremely long formula

Tags: excel, formula, comexception

So here's how you can reproduce this problem:

> 1) Have two workbooks open (call them wb1 and wb2)
>
> 2) Create a formula in wb1, that references cells in the other, and make sure to squeeze in as many cell references as you can before you reach the max character limit (i.e. you can just do "=sum([wb2.xlsx]Sheet1!A1,...,...,[wb2.xlsx]Sheet1!A1)"
>
> 3) Close wb2, so now the path of it gets appended to the wb1 formula. However, since we were already at the limit, it jacks up the formula.

Now, if I try to access the formula property of the cell, I get a COMException thrown. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

When you are closing `wb2`, Excel is probably **changing the path to the full Windows path** of the workbook (i.e. `C:/Documents and settings...`). I'd say you have to change your formula so that it doesn't reach the character limit.

A workaround is to have **intermediate formulas**, something quite dirty (but works) is to have a sheet in wb1 that relates to wb2 (something as simple as `[wb2.xlsx]Sheet1!A1`) and then refer to these cells (they will be in the same workbook then) in your formula.

It's quite dirty but can work. I hope I made myself clear enough.